# Passing Arguments in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to pass arguments in Python and why my code is not working. Why is it saying that the arguments are not defined? I need the arguments in from each function to be able to speak to one another. I could only solve this problem by putting the variables in the defined main function, which is not how I wanted to design the program.

```
#make computer program that takes amount of doughnuts that customer
#wants to order.
#second, multiply the number of doughnuts the customer wants to order
#by the price and the sales tax.
#next, print the price of the doughnut with the sales tax
DOUGHNUT=1.75
SALES_TAX=0.08625

def getNumDoughnuts(numDoughnuts):
    numDoughnuts= raw_input("How many donuts would you like to order?")
    return numDoughnuts

def calculateDoughnutPrice(numDoughnuts, doughnutPrice):
    doughnutPrice=DOUGHNUT*float(numDoughnuts)
    return doughnutPrice

def calculateSalesTax(doughnutPrice, priceWithTax):
    taxAmount= (doughnutPrice*(SALES_TAX))
    priceWithTax= taxAmount+doughnutPrice
    return priceWithTax

def displayPrice(priceWithTax):
    print(priceWithTax)

def main():
    getNumDoughnuts(numDougnuts)
    calculateDoughnutPrice(numDoughnuts, doughnutPrice)
    calculateSalesTax(doughnutPrice, priceWithTax)
    displayPrice(priceWithTax)

main()
```

Comment: You should see how to use Object Oriented Programming, especially in Python. So you can use classes with variables and accessors

Comment: And you should have a look to ho w to format Python code starting by the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @daouzli this question really has nothing to do with OOP. The poster is having trouble distinguishing arguments from return values, as Alex points out. They need to get this fundamental concept before they can move on to OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `main`, `numDougnuts` is indeed not defined when you call `getNumDoughnuts`.  OTOH, the latter function ignores its argument and returns a value, which `main` in turn ignores.  And so forth -- you need to distinguish arguments from return values!

So putting things in proper order your program would become:

```
DOUGHNUT = 1.75
SALES_TAX = 0.08625

def getNumDoughnuts():
    numDoughnuts = raw_input("How many donuts would you like to order?")
    return numDoughnuts

def calculateDoughnutPrice(numDoughnuts):
    doughnutPrice = DOUGHNUT * float(numDoughnuts)
    return doughnutPrice

def calculateSalesTax(doughnutPrice):
    taxAmount = doughnutPrice*(SALES_TAX)
    priceWithTax = taxAmount + doughnutPrice
    return priceWithTax

def displayPrice(priceWithTax):
    print(priceWithTax)

def main():
    numDoughnuts = getNumDoughnuts()
    doughnutPrice = calculateDoughnutPrice(numDoughnuts)
    priceWithTax = calculateSalesTax(doughnutPrice)
    displayPrice(priceWithTax)

main()
```

See the difference between arguments and return values?  Arguments are what gets **into** a function (and their values must be defined at the time you call that function).  A return value is what gets **out** of the function -- and usually needs to be bound to a variable, or otherwise used, by the function's caller.

Also, of course, you need to call `main`, or else nothing happens!-)

Comment: thanks for all the help. it's been a while since i took Python, but i'm starting to remember stuff now thanks to your post. i was trying to communicate to each function through putting the values in the parenthesis but now remember you have to access them in main with the equal sign? Thanks a lot!